# Circle Caustics for a Radiant Point inside the Circle

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, partial-derivative

I'm currently learning about caustics and envelopes and I'm tackling the classic coffee cup caustic. I understand the proof for the cardioid and nephroid. To my understanding, they occur for when the radiant point lies on the circumference and when light rays are parallel respectively. I'm aware that to solve for the envelope I must solve the equation for the family of reflected rays and its partial derivative simultaneously. Then, I came across the Wolfram MathWorld website that documented more shapes for when the radiant point a finite distance away within a unit circle.

The resulting equation is such: [image]

I've started the derivation with the diagram below, but I just have no idea how to define the family of reflected lines to include μ. I would appreciate some pointers for starting this derivation!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this problem, I really enjoy this kind of stuff! I've written up an answer that hopefully explains how to get the result without giving too much away - let me know if I've got that balance wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try to work through this with your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the same result as on Wolfram with the following steps:

1. The "cup" is a unit circle centred at $O$, which we'll take as the origin. Define points $L(\mu,0)$ (the light source), $P(\cos t,\sin t)$ (the point a light ray hits the coffee cup) and let $Q$ be the intersection of the reflected ray with the (extended) line $LO$.
2. The coordinates of $L$ and $P$ allow you to work out $\tan \angle OLP$
3. Using the fact that $\angle OPQ = \angle OPL$ (as it's a reflection), with a bit of angle chasing you can find $\angle OQP = \pi-2t+ \angle OLP$
4. This gives you the gradient of $PQ$ (the reflected ray) and since you know it goes through $P$, you can get the equation for that line. After a bit of trig, I found its equation to be $F(x,y,t)=0$, where $F$ is

> $$F(x,y,t) = (\sin{t}-2\mu \sin{2t})x - (\cos{t}-2\mu \cos{2t}) + \mu \cos{t}y$$

5. We want the envelope of these rays as $t$ varies; as usual, this is found by solving
   $$F(x,y,t)=0,\quad\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = 0$$

simultaneously for $x$ and $y$. This gives the result.

I think the trickiest step is (4); it's worth taking time to manipulate the trig functions so the next step is easier. As always, Wolfram|Alpha can be pretty helpful for some of those manipulations!

Comment: Hello! I'm following the solution. I managed to get the same results in step 3 but only with point P in the second quadrant with coordinates $(-cost, sint)$. With positive P coordinates, I got the expression $-\pi - ∠OLP +2t$ instead. Then, I used tan $∠$ to find the gradient of the reflected ray, and substituted the expression for tan $∠$. After manipulating the trig function, I'm still able to get the solution. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: It shouldn't make much difference, but I took $\mu$ to be negative. It's possible this will have an effect on the exact form of the angles, but it shouldn't change the final result.

Comment: I agree. Though, when I substituted the angles in the expression for the gradient, I got the expression $\frac{−(2)−(3)}{(2)+(3)}$, I don't think there should be a triple angle expression... I'll go back and review my steps.

Comment: After taking  to be negative as well, I managed to find the gradient to be $\frac{-sin(2t)-sint}{cos(2t)+cost}$. I also got the equation for $F(x, y, t)=0$ where $F$ is $(cost +  cos(2t))y + (sint+  sin 2t)x = sin2t +  sin3t$ and I was unable to reduce this to match the expression above. I took the partial derivative and using cramer's rule, I found the denominator to be $-3 cost -2^2 -1$ which is pretty close to the solution on Wolfram MathWorld but not quite the same, I've been stuck otherwise. I would appreciate more guidance while not giving too much away, if it's possible!

Comment: I'll double check my calculations (you've got me worried I made a typo now!) but meantime you might want to try just plotting the setup on Geogebra with a variable $\mu$ and $t$. It's a good way to check your workings, especially with messy trig like we're getting here. You can even use the trace function to plot the caustic and check it against the Wolfram expression.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I seemed to have solved the problem by taking tan∠ as negative (- tan∠) because the incident ray forms a negative gradient, which would originally come from an obtuse ∠ but I needed to find the acute angle!

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out.